# How to change value of input

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html structure:

```
<div class="checkout-related-view__related-row last">
  <div class="checkout-related-view__related-row-cell checkout-related-view__related-row-cell--left">
    <input class="checkbox related-checkbox" data-role="none" id="related-checkbox-7085508-020-01077" type="checkbox" value="10">
    <label for="related-checkbox-7085508-020-01077"><span class="checkbox"></span> Old Bed or Mattress Recycling</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkout-related-view__related-row-cell checkout-related-view__related-row-cell--right">
    <span class="price"><span class="currency">£</span>39</span> <a class="checkout-icon checkout-icon-info related-info" data-content="We will collect your old bed frame, mattress, divan base and headboard, and recycle as much as possible into new material."
    data-html="true" data-original-title="Recycling Service" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="0" title=""><span class="visuallyhidden">Recycling Service</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="checkout-related-view__related-row-cell checkout-related-view__related-row-cell--qty">
    <div class="input-combobox input-combobox__with-qty" data-label="Qty" data-range-max="1" data-range-min="0">
      <span class="input-combobox__label">Qty</span>
      <input class="input-combobox__text input-qty" name="related_products[7085508][10][qty]" type="text" value="0">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've try using JS to change the QTY. Unfortunatelly there is no luck.
Please note that the code has no ID. Is there any way how I can set the value using name or class?

The code I've tried and didn't work is :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("input-combobox__text input-qty").value="1";
```

Can you please help?

Comment: Rather than showing code that is working, can you show the code that isn't working that you've tried so we can help fix it?  There are any number of ways of setting the value - let's help fix your approach.

Comment: there is no elements in this snippet with `id = 'related-checkbox-7085601-020-01077'`

Comment: There is no jquery in this question.  Why tag with jquery?

Comment: Why should the quantity change? There doesn't seem to be any indication in the code that it should

Comment: @ND Yep - I suggest you remove the part about setting checkboxes if it's working for you.  It's not the problem you're having, and it seems to be confusing the issue.

Comment: @mikeyq6 I have to set the QTY by default to 1 and I have no access to the html, so I need to find a way to work around using JS or Jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements, and you can't apply `value` to an array. Instead, grab the first item in the returned array:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("input-combobox__text input-qty")[0].value = "1";
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements, if you want to set the `value` of the first match do so

```
document.getElementsByClassName("input-combobox__text input-qty")[0].value="1";
```